# Location parameter was not display in response header for extract access token in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, location, access-token

The location field contains the token value for the next redirecting page. But I am unable to get that token value from the response header to navigate to the next page.

But while we run the browser manually we can see the location filed in the response header.

how can I get an access token without a location parameter else how to get the location parameter in JMeter response header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Azure B2C login we need to follow the below steps:

1. Need to extract CSRF and State Properties from below endpoints

- .........onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_xxx_signup_signin_v2/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- Regex Expression Main sample only : "csrf":"([^"]+)","transId":"StateProperties=([^"]+)

2. Pass above value in below endpoints

- ............/B2C_1_xxx_SignUp_SignIn_V2/client/perftrace?tx=StateProperties=${csrf_sp_g2}&p=B2C_1_xxx_SignUp_SignIn_V2

3.Extract Code value from below endpoints Main and sub sample body : code=([^"]+)

- ....../B2C_1_xxx_SignUp_SignIn_V2/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/confirmed
- PAss above code value in below endpoints parameter
- ......../b2c_1_xxx_signup_signin_v2/oauth2/v2.0/token
- You will find the token value in main sample only and also you will get location parameter in sub sample

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting the same response with JMeter comparing to the real browser it means that you're not sending the same request (or requests sequence)

Try playing with `Redirect automatically` / `Follow redirects` checkboxes, it might be the case JMeter is not properly [redirecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) you to the proper location

[image]

You need to compare the requests originating from JMeter and real browser using:

- either browser developer tools and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
- or using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Once you [configure JMeter to behave exactly like the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you should get the same response including the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header.